# I need to read Google Groups Posts through Google Oauth

Tags: oauth, provisioning, google-groups

I am trying to read Google Groups posts, but I don't understand how to do it.

I've tried with OAuth 2.0 Playground. Google Groups Provisioning  is working fine, but my objective is to  get all of the discussions of a specific group that the current user subscribed to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [API for Google Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757793/api-for-google-groups)

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for Google Groups posts.

Comment: Hi, I got a scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings .Trying to use this with OAuth 2.0 Playground showing error: "accessNotConfigured". I got a discussion on this regard @ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/oumHqVLDNNI

Comment: That discussion is about Google Analytics not Google Groups. And it still doesn't change the fact that there is no API for Groups posts.